# How to bind Ext treepanel's onExpand event

Tags: extjs, treepanel

i tried using tree.on("expand", myMethod);
It is not working, but same syntax for "click" event is working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, event is `expandnode` instead of `expand`.

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeload: function(tree, operation)
```

and **leaf** property must be set false or not set at all.